# wordpress duplicator site migration issue

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

For sitre migration using wordpress duplicator plugin last time i got install database test failure how to fix this issue. this is the first time iam facing this issue.Please check [image]

Answer (score 0):

This plugin doesn't support for MySQL version lower than 5.5.3, that means you need to upgrade MySQL on your server/hosting to new version which can be compatible with this plugin. If you can't do it because server/hosting doesn't support, you can't use this plugin anymore.

Comment: thx for your answer. but last week i tried the same plugin with same hosting server there was no issue.